# How to make a randomize answer quiz game with IEnumerator in Unity?

Tags: c#, arrays, random, shuffle, ienumerator

```
//data for display
{newQues = "abc"; string[] ans = { "abc", "bcd", "cde", "def" }; answer = "abc"; }

public IEnumerator DisplayQues() //use to display question
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.25f);
    Ques.GetComponent<Text>().text = newQues;

    ansNum = Random.Range(0, ans.Length);
    AnsA = ans[ansNum];
    ans = ans.Except(new string[] { ans[ansNum] }).ToArray();
    ansNum = Random.Range(0, ans.Length);
    AnsB = ans[ansNum];
    ans = ans.Except(new string[] { ans[ansNum] }).ToArray();
    ansNum = Random.Range(0, ans.Length);
    AnsC = ans[ansNum];
    ans = ans.Except(new string[] { ans[ansNum] }).ToArray();
    ansNum = Random.Range(0, ans.Length);
    AnsD = ans[ansNum];
    ans = ans.Except(new string[] { ans[ansNum] }).ToArray();

    AnswerA.GetComponent<Text>().text = AnsA;
    AnswerB.GetComponent<Text>().text = AnsB;
    AnswerC.GetComponent<Text>().text = AnsC;
    AnswerD.GetComponent<Text>().text = AnsD;
}
```

It show "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object" when playing the scene.

There's an error occur in line `ansNum = Random.Range(0, ans.Length);`

How to replace these code?

```
ansNum = Random.Range(0, ans.Length);
AnsA = ans[ansNum];
ans = ans.Except(new string[] { ans[ansNum] }).ToArray();
ansNum = Random.Range(0, ans.Length);
AnsB = ans[ansNum];
ans = ans.Except(new string[] { ans[ansNum] }).ToArray();
ansNum = Random.Range(0, ans.Length);
AnsC = ans[ansNum];
ans = ans.Except(new string[] { ans[ansNum] }).ToArray();
ansNum = Random.Range(0, ans.Length);
AnsD = ans[ansNum];
ans = ans.Except(new string[] { ans[ansNum] }).ToArray();
```

Comment: string[] input = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f" };
            Random rand = new Random();
            string[] results = input.Select(x => new { r = rand.Next(), i = x }).OrderBy(x => x.r).Select(x => x.i).ToArray();